# How to create diagonal boxes using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create diagonal box inside box. How can I do this using css.

I am attaching an image, exactly what i want. If any one have any idea please share with me.

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8Wv/660/

[image]

My codes are here:

HTML:

```
<div class="foo bg1"></div>
<div class="foo bg2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {   
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);    
}

.bg1 {
    background-color:#13b4ff;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color:#ab3fdd; 
}
```

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8Wv/660/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making divs absolute may disturb other elements. You can also move the second div inside first div and apply margin on second div like shown in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6k9Ltyoa/

```
<div class="foo bg1">
    <div class="foo bg2"></div>
</div>

.foo {   
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.bg1 {
    background-color:#13b4ff;
}

.bg2 {
    background-color:#ab3fdd;
    margin-top:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8Wv/661/
  you can position the second div and assign top,left.

```
.bg2 {
background-color:#ab3fdd;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add some absolute position to the second box. I'd recommend wrapping it all up to make it responsive too with the container having relative positioning. Use the left/top % values to move the box, greater increase will move them further respectively.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8Wv/662/

```
.bg2 {
background-color:#ab3fdd;
position:absolute;
left:2%;
top:2%;
}
```

I added the wrapper for you here too. Up to you whether or not you want it :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Ae8Wv/665/

Answer (score 1):

Give the `.bg2` div a `position: absolute;`. And don't forget to put a `position: relative;` on `.bg1`, or else the absolute positioning won't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo bg1">
    <div class="foo bg2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {   
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.bg1 {
    background-color:#13b4ff;
}

.bg2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color:#ab3fdd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/Ae8Wv/671/

Comment: Why would he put relative positioning on .bg1? Adding it to .foo will make no difference either? In fact you only need relative positioning for some kind of wrapper. I'm not sure I follow your logic.

Comment: I assumed he wanted the absolute positioned element to be relative positioned to it's parent. So you have much more control over the position of the absolute positioned element. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: It's not the parent. It's a separate div just for reference.

Comment: You are right. Silly of me. I edited the example and fiddle. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Just add some margin to the purple box like this
http://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/Ae8Wv/667/

```
.bg2 {
    background-color:#ab3fdd;
    margin-left:-30px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about translations?

```
.bg2{transform: translate(-40px, 20px)}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/Ae8Wv/669/)